# Adding Swing Component to PDF File

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

Is there any method to add JTextbox, JButton, JLable in Pdf file through java coding using iText?

How can I add such component in pdf file? So that by using `setLayout` and `setBounds` method I can place them any where in my PDF file through java coding.

Comment: Do you want to just include a graphical representation of a Swing control (i.e. a static image), or make them functional objects (which isn't possible, of course)?

Comment: What you can do is print Swing components to a PDF with iText: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2006/jw-1209-swing.html

Comment: It would be nice to mark answers as solution...

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this. Swing Components are Java Classes and can't be used inside PDF Files.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "copy" / screenshot image of the Swing component, but not the component itself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use swing components in pdfs. However pdf allows to create fields in pdf with Acrobat Reader/Pro. If you want to do it programatically with java, so there is a tutorial with iText [here](http://www.geek-tutorials.com/java/itext/itext_acroform_javascript.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can do other way round.Open a pdf file using `Swing` components and add desired effects.Here is a [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/324198/java/java/Launching-applications-Java-GUI) you can follow.